# ObjectMapper - Initialize an empty init in child class

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I have a base class called "Base" that implements the Mappable protocol. I already subclassing that class as described below.

```
class Base: Mappable {
    var base: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        base <- map["base"]
    }
}

class Subclass: Base {
    var sub: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        super.init(map: map))
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)

        sub <- map["sub"]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create an empty init in subclass that how i can create an instance of subclass like this?

```
var obj = Subclass()
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to? I get the feeling there is some information missing in this question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I didn't miss anything, whenever i try this i'm getting `Missing argument for parameter 'map' in call`

Comment: I didn't say anything was missing from your code but rather information regarding the question so that we can fully understand it. Looking at the accepted answer I assume it has something to do with `Mappable` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `init()` inside your `Base` and `override init()` inside your `SubClass`

```
class Base: Mappable {
    var base: String?

    init() {}

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        base <- map["base"]
    }
}

class Subclass: Base {
    var sub: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(map: Map) {
        fatalError("init(map:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map: map)

        sub <- map["sub"]
    }
}
```

Comment: But it didn't allow me to create object as `var obj = Subclass()`

Comment: @MuhammadArifulIslam what ObjectMapper version do you use?

Comment: @MuhammadArifulIslam Don't you forget to add `init() {}` to `Base` and `override init() { super.init() }` to `Subclass`?

Comment: you can replace your code with my code. I've tested it and I can declare empty SubClass as `var subClass = SubClass()` as shown in the [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l1daMhYPaMYxXf5nRAsWyto7lZOeozZc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @RomanPodymov I tried with it before and didn't work, now after clean and build its working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LyBoung Yes, I do that and working for me, Thanks.

Comment: Glad this helps. :)